# Web platform installer.. why? and how to install the SEO Toolkit?

Tags: windows, seo

How do you use the Web platform installer to install the SEO Toolkit from http://www.microsoft.com/web/spotlight/seo/? If I choose application, I have to choose an application through a file dialog.  If I choose OK, I get a 'The product you are trying to install is not supported on your operation system" message. What!? I am using Windows XP SP3.

and why this new way of installing applications? What's wrong with downloading an .exe. or .msi file? This thing seems to be made for newbies. It frustrated me instead of being anything better than the traditional previous installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Web Platform Installer, then you can download the SEO toolkit from this page: http://www.iis.net/expand/SEOToolkit

The advantage of the WPI is that it automatically installs any dependencies required by the selected application.

Comment: Thanks. They should have offered a seperate download option like the IIS site but since it's an IIS 7 only, It's not useful for me.

Can't a regular installer install any dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

SEO Toolkit requires IIS 7 or greater on the client machine running the tool, which means Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: This requirement should have been stated clearly on the page. Nothing tells me that this is NOT your typical desktop app and that it requires a specific version of IIS. Why people are promoting this as if it's a general app for the public?